# MS SQL combining horizontally select results for the same table

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with following columns: time, portfolioID, MTD where MTD is changing with time for each portfolioID. I want to create a select which shows following: portfolioID, MTD for time1, MTD for time2 etc.

[image]

I don't know how to achieve the following result:

[image]

Please advise!!

Comment: Please tag your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance the possible `time` values, you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    portfolioid,
    max(case when time = '20200803' then mtd end) mdt_for_20200803,
    max(case when time = '20200804' then mtd end) mdt_for_20200804,
    max(case when time = '20200805' then mtd end) mdt_for_20200805
from mytable
group by portfolioid
```

You can expand the `select` clause with more conditional expressions to handle more possible values.

If you don't know the values beforehand, then pure SQL cannot do what you want (a query *always* return the same set of columns). You need dynamic SQL, which is more tedious, and highly database-dependent.

Comment: It works perfectly. Why "case when" doesn't work without max in this case? thank you!

Comment: @Łukasz: we want only one record per portfolio, so we need aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **pivot**

```
SELECT  *
from t2
pivot(MAX(MTD) for [Time]  in ([20200803] , [20200804], [20200805])) pv
```

Here use Max(MTD), because if you have duplicate / multiple same rows then it will require to pick single value (Max or SUM or AVG etc).